# Session times out after 5 minutes, even though the session-timeout parameter is set to 30

Tags: android, servlets, tomcat7, android-volley, session-timeout

I have an android app that sends a request to the server via Volley:

```
        private void waitForForfeit(final String user_id, final String accessToken) {
        String url = "";

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);

        try {
            url = "https://www.chiaramail.com:443/GameServer/GameServer?user_ID=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_id, "UTF-8") + "&token=" + URLEncoder.encode(accessToken, "UTF-8") + "&cmd=" + URLEncoder.encode("WAITFOR FORFEIT ", "UTF-8") + "&parms=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_id, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.wait_forfeit_error) + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            waitForForfeit(user_id, accessToken);
        }

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if (!response.startsWith("41 ")) {
                            queue_builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.wait_forfeit_error) + " " + response);
                            queue_alert = queue_builder.create();
                            queue_alert.show();
                        } else {
                            forfeitAlert.show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                volleyError = error;
                Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.wait_forfeit_error) + volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                waitForForfeit(user_id, accessToken);
            }
        });
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                60*1000*60,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

I've confirmed that the request is being received and processed correctly by the server. The request was designed to return only when a certain event has occurred (another app sends a request that results in the server returning a "41 " response) and this runs correctly.

The problem is that if the second app doesn't send its request within 5 minutes, then the first app experiences a VolleyError. This is even though the session timeout is set to 30 minutes:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        60
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Anyone here have a clue about why this is happening? I've Googled around for a five-minute timeout in Tomcat and couldn't find anything. I also grepped the server config files, looking for 300000, 300 and 600 (five minutes in ms, seconds and minutes) and there was nothing configured with any of these values. What am I missing? I've spent nearly a week on this and it's getting kinda old.

Answer (score 0):

The five-minute timeout is from the Apache server, not Tomcat. After I changed the Timeout setting in the Apache httpd.conf file from 600 to -1, I got the unlimited timeout I was looking for.